# Bind a GridControl to a SortedList

Tags: c#, devexpress, sortedlist

I am trying to have a table (a DevExpress GridControl in particular) be bound to a SortedList.  I want the first column of the table to be bound to the Key of the SortedList and the second column to be bound to a field of the object in the key of the SortedList, for example,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeTable();
    }

    public void InitializeTable()
    {
        SortedList<DateTime, Dividend> EquityDividends = new SortedList<DateTime, Dividend>();

        EquityDividends.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 12, 16, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Local), new Dividend(new DateTime(2011, 1, 12, 16, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Local), "120", 12, new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0)));
        EquityDividends.Add(new DateTime(2011, 1, 13, 16, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Local), new Dividend(new DateTime(2011, 1, 12, 16, 30, 00, DateTimeKind.Local), "125", 12, new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0)));

        gridControl1.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = EquityDividends };

        bandedGridView1.Columns[1].FieldName = "ExpectedDividend";
    }
}

public class Dividend
{
    public DateTime InDividendDate;
    public string ExpectedDividend;
    public double Adjustment;
    public TimeSpan TimeRemaining;

    public Dividend(
        DateTime InDividendDate,
        string ExpectedDividend,
        double Adjustment,
        TimeSpan TimeRemaining)
    {
        this.InDividendDate = InDividendDate;
        this.ExpectedDividend = ExpectedDividend;
        this.Adjustment = Adjustment;
        this.TimeRemaining = TimeRemaining;
    }
}
```

This doesn't quite work (the key comes up in column 0 and a string "WindowsFormsApplication10.Dividend" comes up in column 1).  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just override the method `ToString()` of class `Dividend` and return the value you want like that:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "MyValue";
}
```

You will get one column with the key and one column with the value returned from `ToString()`.

Comment: But what if I want to have multiple columns and have each column tied to a different property of the Dividend class?